# Não consigo Fazer Reports

Tags: c#

O problema não é de como fazer.
Mas não tenho como fazer tudo porque o Reporting que trás o report viewer para desenho do relatório não aparece, já tentei encontra-lo de varias maneiras mas parece que não tem neste meu VS2013 ultimate.
Será que tenho que baixar alguma coisa pra ter o reporting?

Comment: no caso você não esta conseguindo criar o relatório? Ou não está conseguindo mostrar o relatório em uma página?

Comment: Acho que não ficou bem clara a sua dúvida. a) Você não consegue criar um arquivo de relatório (.rdlc por exemplo)? b) Você não consegue montar os relatório porque não aparece o painel "Report Data" com os componentes?

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou utilizar o `ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false,"rel.pdf");`?

Quando não consegui utilizar o view e gerei um relatório em pdf mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta criar um projeto Class Library e criar um .rdlc nele e abri-lo.

Por algum motivo, projetos MVC não reconhecem o editor visual de arquivos .rdlc.